# Scrape with Python , commanded by excel vba

Tags: python, vba, web-scraping

I already had a previous question, but that was pasted in vba tags etc. So I'll try again with proper tags and title since I gained a bit of knowledge now, hopefully.

The problem:
I need to find ~1000 dates from a database [with plant variety data](https://www3.wipo.int/pluto/user/en/index.jsp#) which probably is behind a login so here is a screenshot [image: PLUTO database]. Now I could of course fill out this form ~1000 times but there must be a smarter way to do this. If it were an HTML site I would know what to do, and have vba just pull in the results. I have been reading all morning about these javascript pages and ajax libraries but it is above my level. So hopefully someone can help me out a bit. I also used firebug to see what is going on when I press search:

These codes are similar to the last picture posted, make it easier to read. Code left here for copying.

```
f.cc.facet.limit    
-1
f.cc.facet.mincount 
1
f.end_date.facet.date.end   
2030-01-01T00:00:00Z
f.end_date.facet.date.gap   
+5YEARS
f.end_date.facet.date.oth...    
all
f.end_date.facet.date.sta...    
1945-01-01T00:00:00Z
f.end_type.facet.limit  
20
f.end_type.facet.mincount   
1
f.grant_start_date.facet....    
NOW/YEAR
f.grant_start_date.facet....    
+5YEARS
f.grant_start_date.facet....    
all
f.grant_start_date.facet....    
1900-01-01T00:00:00Z
f.status.facet.limit    
20
f.status.facet.mincount 
1
f.type.facet.limit  
20
f.type.facet.mincount   
1
facet   
true
facet.date  
grant_start_date
facet.date  
end_date
facet.field 
cc
facet.field 
type
facet.field 
status
facet.field 
end_type
fl  
uc,cc,type,latin_name,common_name,common_name_en,common_name_others,app_num,app_date,grant_start_date
,den_info,den_final,id
hl  
true
hl.fl   
cc,latin_name,den_info,den_final
hl.fragsize 
5000
hl.requireFieldMatch    
false
json.nl 
map
q   
cc:IT AND latin_name:(Zea Mays) AND den_info:Antilles
qi  
3-9BgbCWwYBd7aIWPU1/onjQ==
rows    
25
sort    
uc asc,score desc
start   
0
type    
upov
wt  
json
```

Source

```
fl=uc%2Ccc%2Ctype%2Clatin_name%2Ccommon_name%2Ccommon_name_en%2Ccommon_name_others%2Capp_num%2Capp_date
%2Cgrant_start_date%2Cden_info%2Cden_final%2Cid&hl=true&hl.fragsize=5000&hl.requireFieldMatch=false&json
.nl=map&wt=json&type=upov&sort=uc%20asc%2Cscore%20desc&rows=25&start=0&qi=3-9BgbCWwYBd7aIWPU1%2FonjQ
%3D%3D&hl.fl=cc%2Clatin_name%2Cden_info%2Cden_final&q=cc%3AIT%20AND%20latin_name%3A(Zea%20Mays)%20AND
%20den_info%3AAntilles&facet=true&f.cc.facet.limit=-1&f.cc.facet.mincount=1&f.type.facet.limit=20&f.type
.facet.mincount=1&f.status.facet.limit=20&f.status.facet.mincount=1&f.end_type.facet.limit=20&f.end_type
.facet.mincount=1&f.grant_start_date.facet.date.start=1900-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&f.grant_start_date.facet
.date.end=NOW%2FYEAR&f.grant_start_date.facet.date.gap=%2B5YEARS&f.grant_start_date.facet.date.other
=all&f.end_date.facet.date.start=1945-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&f.end_date.facet.date.end=2030-01-01T00%3A00
%3A00Z&f.end_date.facet.date.gap=%2B5YEARS&f.end_date.facet.date.other=all&facet.field=cc&facet.field
=type&facet.field=status&facet.field=end_type&facet.date=grant_start_date&facet.date=end_date
```

And this is what it looks like in HTML, atleast according to firebug:

```
{"response":{"start":0,"docs":[{"id":"6751513","grant_start_date":"1999-02-04T22:59:59Z","den_final":"Antilles","app_num":"005642_A 005642","latin_name":"Zea mays L.","common_name_others":["MAIS"],"uc":"ZEAAA_MAY","type":"NLI","app_date":"1997-01-10T22:59:59Z","cc":"IT"}],"numFound":1},"qi":"3-9BgbCWwYBd7aIWPU1/onjQ==","facet_counts":{"facet_queries":{},"facet_ranges":{},"facet_dates":{"end_date":{"after":0,"start":"1945-01-01T00:00:00Z","before":0,"2010-01-01T00:00:00Z":1,"between":1,"end":"2030-01-01T00:00:00Z","gap":"+5YEARS"},"grant_start_date":{"after":0,"1995-01-01T00:00:00Z":1,"start":"1900-01-01T00:00:00Z","before":0,"between":1,"end":"2015-01-01T00:00:00Z","gap":"+5YEARS"}},"facet_intervals":{},"facet_fields":{"status":{"approved":1},"end_type":{"ter":1},"type":{"nli":1},"cc":{"it":1}}},"sv":"bswa1.wipo.int","lastUpdated":1435987857572,"highlighting":{"6751513":{"den_final":["Antilles<\/em>"],"latin_name":["Zea<\/em> mays<\/em> L."],"cc":["IT<\/em>"]}}}
```

Edit:
It uses the GET method and XMLHttpRequest, as can be seen from this screenshot:
[image]

I already found how to make python run from excel vba here [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282767/python-vba-outputting-file-in-directory)
I also downloaded beautiful soup but python is not my kind of language, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Image refered to in comment on answer of Will [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I don't need to use python, I can just use an url, and then import the content into excel. I found out with Fiddler that the URL should become https://www3.wipo.int/pluto/user/jsp/select.jsp? And then the piece of code from the OP goes behind that.

The rest of my solution can be found in [another question I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294225/importing-scraping-an-website-into-excel). It uses no Python but only VBA, which commands IE to open a website and copies the content of it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use Excel to store your search parameters.

2) Run a few manual searches to find out what parameters you need to change on each request.

3) Invoke an http get request to the url that you have found in firebug/Fiddler (the url that it calls when you click "search" manually). See Urllib3 https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

3) Look at Json pickle to help you deal with the json response, saving (serializing) it to a file.

4) Reading and writing data involves IO libraries. Google is your friend. (Possibly easier to save your excel file as a csv and then just read the csv file for your search parameters).

5) Download PyCharm for your python development - it's really good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1) My search parameters are 1 column of names in excel, and two fixed parameters. 2) I made a screenshot of what firebug gives me when doing a request. The picture that is in OP is the auto complete I see now. I will add the picture to the bottom of OP.

Comment: In that picture I see the "q:" which are my search terms, but I can't find how that is put into html format.

Comment: So when you click search on their webpage, it does an http post to a url. The post takes a load of parameters, of which the one you want to change seems to be the one named "q". You don't need to put them into their html form, simply send a post request with the same data structure that their webpage sends to their api. If you use Fiddler, you can mess around changing the "posted" data, and then work out how to create all your 1000 queries by substituting "q"s value.

Comment: Look up sending a form urlencoded http post to an api in python.

Comment: I will try using Fiddler tonight at home. I don't have admin rights on this machine so before I got permission to have it installed I might as well have it done by hand xD

Comment: I found out that the url were the request is direct to is www3.wipo.int/pluto/user/jsp/select.jsp Now I only have to find a way to attach that piece of text mentioned below Code in the OP behind the url